# how to expand the text on clicking the read more button or link?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a js function which toggles between two spans of texts. One is smaller text with class collapsed and the other is full text with class expanded.

here is my js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".expanded").hide();

    $(".expanded, .collapsed").click(function() {
        $(this).parent().children(".expanded, .collapsed").toggle();
    });
});
```

and my html look like this

```
<span class="collapsed">
 some small text
 <a href="javascript:void(0)"> READ MORE>></a>
</span>

<span class="expanded">
 here come the full text to replace the small text
 <a href="javascript:void(0)">Less>></a>
</span>
```

The preset function replaces the text of one part with another. My problem is that when we click on any part of any span either collapsed or expanded, the text is changed. I want to restrict it to change the text only when one click the READ MORE>> or Less>> link. I have gone so far in this design that I cant change the function now. I want changes while staying the in present function. Any ideas??

Comment: When it's expanded, where is the full text added? in the span after the a tag ?

Comment: The full text is added in the expanded span before the link.

Comment: right now the function is expanding the text by clicking any where in the collapsed span either on link or on text. this is the problem i want to restrict it on the link only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".expanded").hide();

    $(".expanded a, .collapsed a").click(function(eve) {
        eve.preventDefault();
        $(".expanded, .collapsed").toggle();
    });
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L9nLfdmp/)

**UPDATE**

To solve the problem related to the posts.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".expanded").hide();

    $(".expanded a, .collapsed a").click(function(eve) {
        var $container = $(this).parents("div");
        eve.preventDefault();
        $container.children(".expanded, .collapsed").toggle();
    });
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L9nLfdmp/1/)

Note that this code takes for granted that the spans are contained in a div (change if otherwise).

Hope that helps or at least gives you some ideas.

Kind regards.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks brother.. that's what i was looking for. And thank you especially for helping me on Christmas day, I was not expecting answer today..lol.. thanks alot

Comment: sorry, its still making problems. now it expand all the posts having expanded class with them. I have at least 5-10 post which have this structure so they all got expanded and collapsed when any one of the link is clicked.

Comment: @MianKamran Hi there, please check the update, I'm leaving for a while (I have to take out the dog LOL) anyway, hope it helps

Answer (score 5):

You can use [Readmore.js](http://jedfoster.com/Readmore.js/)

```
$('#read').readmore({
  speed: 75,
  maxHeight: 100
});
```

**[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/qj51ppyz/)**

Comment: brother I cant use id's in the function, I am making a dynamic website. so I use a class to target it. Which was needed to be responsive also. so all what i want was being achieved by the function I have mentioned earlier. I have seen a lot of examples and demos before. i know a lot of functions also. I need help regarding the function i have mentioned. can You please edit that to make something nice for me

Comment: @MianKamran so use a class name instead. It's a standard jquery selector.

Answer (score 1):

How about this ? this will work on classes and is expandable.

```js
$(".expanded a, .collapsed a").click(function() {
        $(this).parent().children(".expanded, .collapsed").toggle();
    });
```

Comment: you can animate the toggling so it makes it a bit nicer, have a look [HERE, Jquery toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/). Mark the question as answered if you could. Thanks

Comment: That is great but I am late to apply it now. can you please recommend something about the function I have provided? Please

Comment: My question was about suggesting some edits while staying in my code.

Answer (score 1):

**Use this jQuery snippet to dig this issue**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery(".expanded").hide();
  jQuery(".collapsed a").click(function() {
    jQuery(this).hide();
    jQuery(".expanded").slideDown();
  }); 
  jQuery(".expanded a").click(function(){
    jQuery(".expanded").slideUp();
    jQuery(".collapsed a").show();
  });
});
```