# link "see more" in the text box, at the overflow

Tags: html, css

I need to cut responsive text on line 4, like this :

[image: example of what I want]

I did it like this:

```js
$(".show-more").on('click', function(){
    $('.text').css('display', 'block');
    $(this).css('display', 'none');
    return false;
});
```

```css
.show-more{
        position: absolute;
        display: block;
        padding:0;
        margin: 0;
        font-size: 11px;
        line-height: 16px;
        font-weight: 400;
        border: none;
        outline: none;
        right: 0px;
        height: 24px;
        width: 93px;
        text-align: left;
        transform: translateY(-20px);
    }
 .text{
        width: auto;
        margin: 0 16px;
        font-size: 11px;
        line-height: 16px;
        font-weight: 400;
        margin-top: -33px;
        display: -webkit-box;
        -webkit-line-clamp: 4;
        -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
```

```html
<p class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</p>
<button class="show-more">...  see-more</button>
```

I need to add a 'see more' link but at the end of the fourth line.

Currently, I added a button with the text and then placed it in absolute above the text.

I am looking for a 'cleaner' method because the text can be cut in the middle of a letter.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to expand the text on clicking the read more button or link?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27646284/how-to-expand-the-text-on-clicking-the-read-more-button-or-link)

Comment: Hi, I just read and it doesn't seem to fit, as I need to cut to line 4 regardless of the width of the window.

Comment: The code snippet does not work anymore.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this using only a link `<a>` element in your paragraph:

```html
<p class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
  in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum
  <a href="" class="show-more">... see-more</a>
</p>
```

Comment: It's hidden by overflow :/, or i didn't use it well ?

Comment: @Max Try it without your styles ;)

Comment: I've tried but the                      display: -webkit-box;
        -webkit-line-clamp: 4;
        -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
        overflow: hidden; is important to cut at line 4 and it overflow the anchor tag

Comment: As you can see here, i can't deal with it https://jsfiddle.net/8tmyz6xw/
i can make a link under but not inside the text block.

Comment: @Max Would be something like this ok for you ? https://jsfiddle.net/1h9adgkq/9/

Comment: it need to be at the end on the line, that the hard trick, thanks for your help ;) i have a complex solution for this i think, just try it now.

Comment: If I click in the code snippet on see-more, the page gets emptied. jsfiddle.net/1h9adgkq/9 does not work either, see-more is not clickable.

Comment: @Timo Normal it's just a link in this case so in the code snippet it redirect you to an empty page. In the js-fiddle there is no `href` so nothing will happen ;)